# Is there a way to find out what Azure DevOps features/settings are making use of an active Personal Access Token (PAT)?

Tags: security, azure-devops, continuous-integration, access-token, continuous-deployment

#### Context

In an Azure DevOps user's Personal Access Tokens settings (https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_usersSettings/tokens) tokens listed note their status, organizations associated, expiration date, and associated permissions.

#### Question

Is any way to determine for a token listed, where it is used? Ex. I see several tokens with Code (R/W) and Packaging (Read) but am not certain which bits of DevOps within the organization are using which token.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below help you? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is any way to determine for a token listed, where it is used?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid the answer is negative. Personal access tokens (PATs) are alternate passwords that you can use to authenticate into Azure DevOps. It's just a password, it's another form of user authentication. We could not track its usage based on a password. It can be used in any project code, build pipeline, release pipeline, etc.

It's like we have defined an environment variable on our computer, it is almost impossible to find out all the records of its use

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Leo. I understand it is like a password, but it is not uncommon for systems to log "login attempts". For example, a table associated with the keys that displayed something like *mm/dd/yyyy @ 12:30 AM, POST dev.azure.com/foo-service from 123.123.123.123* would be extremely helpful for monitoring and administration.